# Coinflip Embed Command Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about making a coinflip embed command.
What I want it to do is make a discord embed saying **Coinflip | (Bot Name)** as the header, then the field is "(User who used the command) the coin landed on (what it lands on)! and then the thumbnail is a picture of a coin flipped on tails or heads.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor. I recommend reading the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

#### Method

You can import choice from random, and use the number 1 and 0 to make determine your coinflip by doing something like `if random.choice(number) == 1:`.

#### Example

```py
import random
from random import choice

determine_flip = [1, 0]

@bot.commands()
async def coinflip(ctx):
    if random.choice(determine_flip) == 1:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Coinflip | (Bot Name)", description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Flipped coin, we got **Heads**!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Coinflip | (Bot Name)", description=f"{ctx.author.mention} Flipped coin, we got **Tails**!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

#### Conclusion

I hope this helped, good luck on your Discord Bot, If you're new to discord.py then you can get help from my community and improve your bot and even solve your problems.

Have a nice day!

Join [Senarc](https://senarc.org/discord) if you need help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

````
async def _coinflipl(ctx):
    responses = ['heads.',
                 'tails.']
    await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(responses)}") ```
````